# How many different values can $(x^2 + y^2, x^2 + 2y^2 )$ have mod 4?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, algebraic-geometry, quadratic-forms

It is known that if a prime number $p = x^2 + y^2 $ is equivalent to $p \equiv 1 \mod 4$.  This is Fermat's theorem on the sum of two squares.

---

My question is about the value of two simultaneous quadratic forms.  Consider the values:

$$ (x,y) \in \mathbb{Z}^2 \longrightarrow (x^2 + y^2 , x^2 + 2 \,y^2) $$

Invidually I can find the value of each coordinate modulo 4:

- $x^2 = 0, 1 \mod 4$ e.g. $0,1,4,9,16,25,\dots \equiv 0,1,0,1,0,1,\dots$
- $x^2 + y^2 = \{0 \text{ or } 1\} + \{0 \text{ or } 1\} = \{0,1 \text{ or } 2\}$ modulo $4$.
- $x^2 + y^2 = \{0 \text{ or } 1\} + 2\times\{0 \text{ or } 1\} = \{0,1,2 \text{ or } 3\}$ modulo $4$.

Then $x^2 + y^2$ can take any 3 out of the 4 possible values and $x^2 + 2y^2$ can take all possible values, so that $(x^2 + y^2 , x^2 + 2 \,y^2) $ can be one of $3 \times 4 = 12$ of $4^2 = 16$ possible values, but if we plot:

[image]
[image]

Only (0,0), (1,1), (1,2) and (2,3)... Why can't we get all $12$ possibilites?

---

Similarly, we don't get all $11 \times 11 = 121$ possibilities mod $11$.

**Question** - what fraction of the $m^2$ possible values can we obtain mod $m$?

As a function of $m$ the value do not fit into any [OEIS](https://oeis.org/search?q=1%2C4%2C4%2C4%2C9%2C16%2C16) sequence.

```
  1,   4,   4,   4,   9, 
 16,  16,   9,  16,  36, 
 36,  16,  49,  64,  36, 
 16,  81,  64, 100,  36, 
 64, 144, 144,  36, 121, 
196, 121,  64, 225
```

Comment: Well, for one your pairs $(a,b)$ satisfy "$(b-a)$ is a square $mod(4)$ (or $mod(11)$".

Comment: @lulu Here's a nice general question:  what fraction of the $m^2$ possible values can $(x^2 + y^2 , x^2 + 2y^2)$ take  mod $m$ ?  I can still change it...

Comment: Well, in light of my earlier comment this is determined if we know how many classes can be written as a sum of two squares.  That I don't know (which does not mean that it isn't known).

Comment: I don't even know the following:  how many classes $mod(m)$ can be written as $x^2+1$?

Comment: Sorry, I'm wrong.  You are correct...your general question sounds interesting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$x^2$ and $y^2$ modulo 4 can each only take on 2 values.  Thus, there can be at most four distinct combinations of those values, no matter how you arrange them.

Modulo 11, $x^2$ and $y^2$ can take on up to 6 distinct values, so you can have up to 36 possible combinations.

Note that if $(a,b)$ are independent variables, then so are $(a+b,b)$, and likewise $(a+b,a+2b)$.  Thus, since $x^2$ and $y^2$ are independent, so must also be $x^2+y^2,x^2+2y^2$.

Thus, all the combinations show up for any $m$.

For generic $m$, the number of possibilities is $f(m)^2$, where $f(m)$ is the number of distinct values that $x^2$ can take modulo $m$.  For odd primes, $f(m) = (m+1)/2$.

Comment: ...and surely $f$ is [multiplicative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplicative_function) so we are done!

Comment: Good point: if $a$, $b$ are relatively prime, then it must be the case that $f(ab) = f(a)f(b)$.